# Convert all image links in a website directory (on mac)

Tags: macos, sed, replace

My task is to take a directory of website files, including html, css, and non-text image files, and change all image paths from relative paths to a universal cdn path. This is on a mac.

My starting point is something like this:

```
sed -i '' 's/old_link/new_link/g' *
```

but I want it to act only on css,html files, and to recurse through any subdirectories.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `find`.  Soemthing like:

```
find . -name *css -exec sed -i '' 's/old_link/new_link/g' {} ';'
```

will find all the css files in your current directory and below it and pass each one to sed.  The `{}` stand in for the name (and location) of each file that find finds.  Don't omit the quote marks around the final ;

Then repeat for html files.

As ever, for the finer points of syntax consult man, or google for the find documentation.

Comment: You need to quote the glob pattern and use a dot. And you can use `-o` to do both file types in one pass: `find . -name "*.css" -o -name "*.html" ...`