# Just got bashed by my sed script- why?

Tags: macos, bash, sed

Based on the helpful answers I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247783/convert-all-image-links-in-a-website-directory-on-mac), I created the following script, named it convert_image_paths.command, put it in a website folder on my mac and double-clicked it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script will operate on valid relative image paths at this level and one sub-level down, across .html and .css files.

find . -name "*.css" -o -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '' 's/\.\.\/images\//images\//g' {} ';'
find . -name "*.css" -o -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '' 's/images\//http:\/\/mycdn\.com\/images\//g' {} ';'
```

Unfortunately, instead of changing the relative image paths in the website to the new cdn url, it

1. Doubled up the url: http://mycdn.com/http://mycdn.com/images/myimage.png
2. Did that for EVERY html/css file on my machine

So my question is a) is there a tag for moron and b) how do I fix this script?

**EDIT:**

Let me clarify my intention:
I wanted to apply the change to all image paths with relative urls in the form

> "image/{myimagepath}"

or

> "../images/{myimagepath}"

Comment: And this is why you test with -e and only use -i when you know it works.

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with `-e`. Just run it without `-i` first; that's the option that tells sed to edit files in place instead of printing the result to stdout. `-e` tells sed that the next argument is a sed command to execute. `sed -e <expr> <path>` is completely equivalent to `sed <expr> <path>`; it's mostly useful for running multiple commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your second question:

b) Don't do "find ." when you don't know what directory the script is starting from.  If you want it to start from a particular directory, tell it in the find command: `find /Users/ptomblin/Shared/ ...`

As for why it doubled up the URL, it's because you told it to.

```
sed -i '' 's/images\//http:\/\/mycdn\.com\/images\//g' {}
```

Takes every instance of the word "images/" and changed it to "http://mycdn.com/images/", even if it already started with "http://mycdn.com/".  If that's not what you wanted, you're going to have to be more specific about your regexp.

As a first attempt, I would replace BOTH lines with the following

```
find /Users/ptomblin/Shared -name "*.css" -o -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '' 's@".{0,2}/?images@"http://mycdn.com/images@g' {}
```

That will only replace `images` or `../images` if they start with a double quote.

Comment: thanks, so how would I substitute "http://mycdn/images/{myimage}" for "images/{myimage}" without doubling up?

Answer (score 1):

`find .` means "find in the current directory" - so be sure to run this from a directory in which you want to make this substitution in all contents, or change the script to take arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "usage: myscript <path>"
fi

find "$@" ...
```

My guess about why things got doubled is simply that it was run twice; that second substitution in your original script will see "http://mycdn.com/images" and substitute for images again! Here's the obvious way to combine the two substitutions and fix that problem at the same time:

```
sed -i 's@"\(\.\./\|\)images/@"http://mycdn.com/images/@g'
```

Match against the open quote to make sure you don't substitute when there's already an http://..., and optionally match a ../ after it.

I would definitely suggest testing by invoking this on a single file, with results printed to stdout instead of editing in place:

```
sed 's@...@...@' <file>
```

Comment: thanks very much for the path safety code- though I still don't understand how it happened as I def ran it from the relevant directory- As for the regex code, I clarified my intended conversion in the question (see edits)- any good one-liner ideas?

Comment: @Yarin: Edited in a fix. Paul Tomblin's works equally well; we just wrote patterns differently. His is a little shorter, mine's easier to mess with if there's a different possible prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I also figured out why my original script did not recognize it's current directory.  On macs, if you name a script file with the .command extension, it becomes double-clickable.  However, **when you execute it with a double-click**, instead of from the command line, it **changes its working directory to the users home directory!**

myscript.command:

```
echo "pwd = `pwd`"
```

./myscript.command :
pwd = current directory

myscript.command double-clicked : 
pwd = User home directory